# How to add security to Azure Function?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-functions

I’m new at Azure. So i’ve developed  a simple Web app in net core 6 which autenticathes with AZ AD.
I also add to my solución an azure function but the idea is to add JWT to it .
From azure portal i added, authentication but i dont know how to get a token to , for example, test it with postman.

Does someone know how to do this? I’ve Watch a lot of videos but still can’t get it .

Regards

i need help to add security to my az function and be able to add jwt to my web app and to try tokens from postman.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Create an Azure AD Application and add API permissions:

[image]

Generate the **Auth-Code** by using below Endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
client_id=ClientID  
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=RedirectURI  
&response_mode=query  
&scope=[https://management.azure.com/.default](https://management.azure.com/.default "https://management.azure.com/.default")  
&state=12345
```

[image]

To generate the token, I used the below parameters:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token 

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

By using the above generated access token, you can access Azure Function successfully like below:

```json
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/funcapp/functions/function?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]